# Availablity of emulator for iPhone 6 and 6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone

I tried using emulator for iOS 8 in xCode beta for iPhone 5s. Now that iPhone 6 and 6 plus are available, when will the emulator for them be available ?

Answer (score 1):

The Simulators for the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus became available in the Xcode 6 GM. You will need to update to that to access the new Simulators.